# Using datetime to structure date based on value

Tags: mysql

I have following table in my database.

Table

```
ID        Value         Date
F-1       100           2019-08-15 14:12:24
F-1       50            2019-08-10 18:15:19
F-1       50            2019-08-08 19:10:09
F-2       50            2019-07-07 23:12:24
F-2       100           2019-07-07 17:09:18
F-3       100           2019-09-19 13:45:55
F-3       100           2019-09-10 13:00:01
F-4       50            2019-10-01 14:19:04
```

From the above mentioned table, I want to retrieve the information that what was the first value against particular `ID` group by oldest datetime and latest datetime of that particular `ID`.

Required Output:

```
ID           First        Last        Count
F-1          50           100         3
F-2          100          100         2
F-3          100          100         2
F-4          50           Null        1
```

I have tried using case when, but it didn't work.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Im using MySQL version `5.7.25-log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` (MySQL 8+):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) rn_min,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) rn_max
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_min = 1 THEN Value END) AS First,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN MAX(CASE WHEN rn_max = 1 THEN Value END) END AS Last,
    COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    ID
ORDER BY
    ID;
```

Here is a version for MySQL 5.7:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.Date = t2.min_date THEN Value END) AS First,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1
         THEN MAX(CASE WHEN t1.Date = t2.max_date THEN Value END) END AS Last,
    COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, MIN(Date) AS min_date, MAX(Date) AS max_date
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY ID
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
GROUP BY
    t1.ID
ORDER BY
    t1.ID;
```

Comment: @Mike I have also now given you a version which should work on MySQL 5.7.